# How can I build a pojo from spring-data-solr

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

I have a simple solr schema with some params (field1, field2, field3, field4)

I have a POJO like:

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "mypojo")
class MyPojo{
  String field1;
  String field2;
  MyPojo2 pojo2;
}

class MyPojo2{
  String field3;
  String field4;
}
```

When I retrieve the fields with spring data, only field1 and field2 are not empty, field 3 is  null.

Is there a way to tell spring-Data (or spring-data-solr) to build my pojo in a certain way ? Maybe using some annotation?

Thanks.

Comment: One idea. Does Solr support nested documents by default?

Comment: Yes it does, but I rather prefer to keep the schema simple

Comment: So, why you don't extract two fields from MyPojo2 directly in MyPojo?

Comment: Cause the source is a mongo db which has this structure.

Comment: I see, I have idea, but it's need to be checked - @Field annotation, if you'll use it in MyPojo2, probably it will help

Comment: Did you check this SO question? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19120488/2160152

Comment: AFAIK there's no no support for nested structures in solr. Data has to be flattened in order to fit into the index. The same applies to SD Solr just being a wrapper around solrj. But you could try to write a custom Reading/Writing converter taking care.