# How do I store the query from Solr into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, solr

I am thinking that how do I change the following code, so I can store the query from `Solr` into an `ArrayList`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, SolrServerException {
    HttpSolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What are you looking for: ")     
    String look = sc.nextLine();   

    SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery();
    query.setQuery(look);
    query.setFields("id");
    query.setStart(0);    


    QueryResponse response = solr.query(query);
    SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
      System.out.println(results.get(i));
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you know how to use arrayList?

Comment: I assume you want to store the query's result rather than the query itself, but why would you want that? `SolrDocumentList` extends `ArrayList`

Comment: I am thinking that, so later on I can print out the result line by line in JSP. @Aaron

Comment: You should be able to : since `SolrDocumentList` extends `ArrayList`, you can use every method you could use with an `ArrayList`.

Comment: You may also create a small POJO that models your response and use `response.getBeans(...)`, this is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114554/retrieve-object-from-solr

Comment: So now you've asked the same question (and variations thereof) five times.

Comment: I am just trying any method that may work. And I deleted those question that I didn't phrase properly, I am just trying to learn. Peace. @MatsLindh

Answer (score 0):

you are forgetting the important part.. put the info in the list

lets suppose that **response.getResults()** returns an object holding Strings
then you need a list of Strings :)

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList();
SolrDocumentList results = response.getResults();
    for (int i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
      System.out.println(results.get(i));
      myList.add(results.get(i));
    }
```